# Why are there hidden Spark streaming properties?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've just started learning Spark and there are quite a few things that have come up that alarm me.  One of the simplest ones is that it seems there are Spark streaming properties that they don't make public on their [Spark Streaming Configurations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-streaming) documentation.

I came across one such property while looking into a timeout exception that actually took down my block manager and left my receiver running (which is an insane behavior that I haven't figured out yet).  Another user described the same exception [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879092/reliability-issues-with-checkpointing-wal-in-spark-streaming-1-6-0).  I found [this website](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-streaming/spark-streaming-configuration/read) going over some of the configurations mentioned there which are missing from Spark's documentation.

Here are the (super secret) properties that the accepted answer suggested checking out:

```
spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.allowBatching true 
spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.batchingTimeout 15000
```

Why are these other properties not documented?  I've heard this is a common thing in Spark.  Is that true?

Comment: seems like these are exclusive  for spark 1.6 not for latest versions

Comment: I see reference to those in master

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you if it is "true", but only share my experience that I did not come across many undocumented parts in Spark.

What helped me a lot is also the GitHub book [The Internals of Apache Spark](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/apache-spark-internals/latest/index.html) by Jacek Laskowski.

As Spark is open source, you always have the chance to:

- contribute missing documentation parts
- scan the source code (whereas looking for something you don't know exists in advance will be challenging)